# Why does autofac double dispose my disposable?

Tags: c#, autofac

Hi this seems wrong to me. Is this the way it was designed?

My disposable class:

```
class C : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing C");
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
cb.RegisterInstance(new C());
```

Usage:

```
using (IContainer container = BuildContainer())
{
    var c = container.Resolve<C>();
    Console.WriteLine("C resolved");
}
```

Output:

```
C resolved
Disposing C
Disposing C
```

I think its a bad thing to call Dispose multiple times on the same object.

Note:
When I register the class like this

```
cb.Register(c => new C());
```

It gets disposed only once. Why the difference?

Comment: How many C instances are there? I would also put a WriteLine inside a constructor.

Comment: I am not familiar with Autofaq but it looks like the difference is between registering an instance versus registering a factory. In the first example an instance maybe disposed twice due to the way Autofaq disposes of registered "components" with the second dispose being due to Autofaq disposing the registered "services" or resolvers (in this case the instance itself) when the Autofaq container itself is disposed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I think its a bad thing to call Dispose multiple times on the same object.

It isn't, `Dispose` is supposed to be safe to call multiple times. From the documentation: ["The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) Because this is supposed to be safe, you shouldn't rely on other libraries only calling it once, and there's nothing wrong with changes that you feel shouldn't make a difference causing multiple `Dispose` calls.

Comment: Good point, but that's just an advice that somebody may just ignore. Besides this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: hvd is correct, your main concern would only apply to broken implementations of C

Comment: @Kugel ignoring the documented API is also called "doing it wrong", and frankly represents a bug in the person implementing IDisposable. I don't disagree that the container should *try* to only dispose it once, however: given the choice I'll take "disposed 17 times" in preference to "not disposed" every single day.

Comment: @Kugel No, that's not just advice that somebody may ignore. If your `Dispose` *isn't* safe to call multiple times, **you don't fulfill the requirements of IDisposable**, and the problem is in your code. As for not answering your question, yes, you're right. This is the reason why the question you ask is the wrong question.

Comment: I agree with what you all. It's better to have implementation more robust than rely on callers calling dispose just once. I was just curious why Autofac behaves this way.

Answer (score 8):

Examining the AutoFac source code reveals the reason for this double dispose.

The RegisterInstance extension method wraps the provided instance (c in this case) in a ProvidedInstanceActivator, and keeps this in a collection of activators. When the builder is disposed then any stored activators are disposed and so are their contained objects (assuming they support IDisposable).

Resolved objects (via Resolve) are also tracked in a LifetimeScope container which also disposes its objects when the builder is disposed.

Because AutoFac doesn't determine if a resolved object was originally a provided instance then this double dispose occurs for this style of registration only.

This may or may not be a bug, depending on your point of view, but is harmless if the disposable object is written correctly as mentioned @hvd.

Answer (score 2):

Hvd was right: you should be prepare your disposable class to allow multiple `Dispose` calls. This is the correct way of implementing the disposable pattern as described in multiple places like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) or [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)

Back to your original question:

Autofac automatically call `Dispose` on each component which resolved during a lifetime scope if the component is `IDisposable` (in your example the lifetime scope is the lifetime of the container but it can be any other life time scope). So this is one "Disposing C".

And if you have registered a component with `RegisterInstance` then it calls `Dispose` on them when the container is disposed (even if they are never Resolved!). This is the second "Disposing C".

You can turn this extra dispose off using `ExternallyOwned`:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new C()).ExternallyOwned();
```

When you used `cb.Register(c => new C());` then Autofac creates the `C` instance for you when you call `Resolve` so it can track it (it's not "externally owned") so it only calls once `Dispose` when the litetime scope ends.

You can read more about Autofac's [Deterministic Disposal](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal).

Comment: I understand that autofac owns all disposables and disposes them unless specified otherwise. I just thought it would take care not to dispose same instance twice.

Comment: Apparently Autofac isn't take care because as stated it shouldn't be a problem to call `Dispose` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The Dispose pattern is very easy to get wrong, You need to think of it as a potentially two step thing.

1. Clearing up any allocated unmanaged resources. (eg freeing memory or calling shutdown functions)
2. Clearing up any managed resources.

The most common way of doing this is what I like to call [a double dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private bool _disposed = false;
    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // stop the GC clearing us up, 
    }
    protected virtual Dispose(bool disposing){
        if ( !_disposed ){
            if ( disposing ){
                // someone called Dispose()

                // dispose any other IDispose objects we have
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If your shutdown code needs it, you might have to put a lock around the contents of the Dispose(bool) method.

Comment: Alternately (in order): 1) Do not use unmanaged resources. (Then you don't need to use the 'disposing' pattern, just implement `Dispose()`.) 2) Do not directly hold unmanaged resources, instead implement `SafeHandle` (which already implements the disposing pattern correctly). 3) Create a specialized class only for handling the unmanaged resource and implement disposing pattern there (this class should not hold any managed resources). (Under normal circumstances, the disposing pattern is an overkill.)